# Top bar overlapping header when scroll down and then scroll Up again Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Here is my top bar: https://nationalvip.pixl.work/

The top bar is above the header and looks nice currently.

Problem come when you scroll down and scroll up, the blue top bar will overlap the Header and looks bad.

Here is my css:

```
.top-bar-new {
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999999;
top: 0;
height: 30px;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1800px;
background-color: #164166;
color: #fff;
text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but I solved it. Add this to your CSS (or find it in your css and change 'top' to this):

```
#autohide-header.fixed {
    top: 30px;
}
```

And then change `position: absolute;` in your`.top-bar-new` to `position: fixed;`